# Как присвоить оператор +? "Невозможно присвоить оператор + к IntPtr и int"

Tags: c#

В версии framework 4.6.1 все присваивается, а вот в 3.5 ошибку получаю такого типа:

> Невозможно присвоить оператор + к IntPtr и int

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    byte read = ReadBytes(address + bytes.Count, 1)[0];

    if (read != 0x00)
        bytes.Add(read);
    else break;
}
```

Посоветуйте как к 3.5 адаптировать

---

Дополнил

```
if (!GetExports(cfg.Target.MonoModuleAddress, cfg.Target.Process.Is64Bit()))
   throw new ApplicationException("Unable to obtain the mono function addresses");
```

Comment: в какой конкретно строчке ошибка

Comment: `а вот в 3.5 ошибку получаю` - Какую?

Comment: получаю невозможно присвоить оператор + к IntPtr и int в address + bytes.Count

Comment: Капитан Очевидность подсказывает, что нельзя складывать операнды разных типов, сначала нужно привести к чему-то одному. Сделайте явное приведение типов. И, писать на .Net Framework 3.5 в 2018 году - это уже не очень хороший выбор. Вы б ещё под IE 6.0  пробовали писать...

Comment: @AK я ждал тебя капитан!

Comment: почему в framework 4.6.1 нету такой ошибки

Comment: @AK Кэп в треде, расходимся )

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.op_addition?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2 такие возможности появились только с версией фреймворка 4.0

Comment: Есть ли способ сделать так на 3.5?

Comment: Используйте метод `IntPtr.ToInt32`.

Comment: new IntPtr(address.ToInt64() + bytes.Count) думаю так будит работать?

Comment: Я даже незнаю чего вы ожидайте. Нам не извстен тип переменных которые вы используйте в вашем цикле, можете хотябы до цикла обьявить переменные что бы было ясно с чем работать

Answer (score 3):

Если посмотреть в [документации к оператору добавления](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6522589/2881286) можно увидеть, что этот оператор был введен начиная с *.NET 4*.

Для *.NET 3.5* можно попробовать использовать следующее:

```
new IntPtr(address.ToInt64() + bytes.Count)
```

Правда теперь нужно будет надеяться, что это не будет запускаться на 32-х битной системе с указателем, который больше `int.MaxValue` :)

<sub>[Перевод ответа @JonSkeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6522589/2881286)</sub>

Comment: У меня X32 - код такого типа не работает

Comment: @Вячеслав, какую ошибку пишет? пробовал ли ToInt32?

Comment: @gGrundy я дополню вопрос

Comment: @Вячеслав, я не совсем понял как к вопросу дополнение относится

Answer (score 1):

[**Здесь указано**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.op_addition?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), что такая возможность как добавление **`IntPtr`** и **`int`**, появилась только с версией framework 4.0, так что вам придется использовать явное приведение типов.

Ссылка на [ответ англоязычной версии сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522571/adding-intptr-to-int-generate-error-on-net-framework-3-5).