# Как сложить IntPtr + int?

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите как прибавить int к IntPtr в Cи языке?

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) const char* Plus(IntPtr intptr, int ints)
{
   Что тут нужно прописать, чтобы добавить int?
   return итоговый IntPrt;
}
```

Comment: А по смыслу, что должно получиться после сложения? (указатель intptr должен сместиться на ints элементов или ints байтов?)

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan в Net есть оператор + для int и IntPtr - У меня net 3.5 и нужно сложить 2 этих параметра - альтернативу на Cи ищу чтобы через dllimport передать и получить значение

Comment: [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/870874/184217) обсуждали недавно. Используйте метод `ToInt**`.

Comment: Мне на Cи нужно

Comment: В Си нет `IntPtr`.

Comment: наверное вы хотите  *intptr += ints; прибавить значение переменной на который указывает intptr

Comment: Что такое `IntPtr`? Почему сумма `IntPtr` и `int` должна возвращаться как `const char *`? Пока что вопрос бессмыслен. Сформулируйте вопрос осмысленно.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov: А в C++ разве есть?